# Using PowerShell to add an Availability Set to Backend Pool for Azure Load Balancer

Tags: powershell, azure

Despite having used the official documentation, I'm struggling to find the right PowerShell to associate an availability set (of 2 VMs) with their first IP, to the backend pool configuration for an Azure load balancer.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Get-AzureRmAvailabilitySet` to get and then enumerate the VMs in the availability set. Then use `Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface` to set the `LoadBalancerBackendAddressPool` on each of the VMs NICs?

This link has some good code around this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/networking/scripts/load-balancer-windows-powershell-sample-nlb

Comment: Thanks Tim. It appears that a NI object does indeed have a `LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools` property, but `Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface` has no easy parameter to edit that value. I tried `$NetworkInterfaces[0].IpConfigurations.LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools = $backendPool` (where [0] is the NIC object I wish to edit) and thought perhaps this could be piped to the Set cmdlet, but then get `The property 'LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.` - this is despite copying and pasting the property name from the output.

Comment: Using your logic (i.e. rather than editing the NLB object to contain the network interfaces, editing the network interfaces to contain the NLB data) it was possible using: `Set-AzureRmNetworkInterfaceIpConfig` and then `Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface`. I'll type up the complete answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same issue where I my goal was to update the Load Balancer backendPool based on the machines in an Availability Set.

I created a script:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Updates the Azure Load Balancer backend Pool
.DESCRIPTION
    Add's vm's to the backend pool of the specified Azure Load Balancer.
.OUTPUTS
    Progress messages
#>
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [string]$loadBalancerName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [string]$resourceGroupName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [string]$debugDeploymentDebugLevel,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [string]$availabilitySetName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [string]$backendPoolName
)

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

Try {
    $loadBalancer = Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer `
        -Name $loadBalancerName `
        -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
        -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch {
    Write-Warning "No Load Balancer found with name $loadBalancerName in resource group $resourceGroupName"
    Return
}

try {
    $backendPool = Get-AzureRmLoadBalancerBackendAddressPoolConfig `
        -Name $backendPoolName `
        -LoadBalancer $loadBalancer
}
catch {
    #Write-Warning "no Backend Pool found with the name $backendPoolName in the load balancer with the name $loadBalancerName"
    Return
}

try {
    $AvSet = Get-AzureRmAvailabilitySet `
        -Name $availabilitySetName `
        -ResourceGroupName (Get-AzureRmResource | Where-Object {
            ($_.Name -eq $availabilitySetName) -and `
            ($_.ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.Compute/AvailabilitySets")}).ResourceGroupName
}
catch {
    Write-Warning "no AvailabilitySet found with the name $availabilitySetName in resource group $availabilitySetResourceGroup"
    Return
}

ForEach ($id in $avSet.VirtualMachinesReferences.id) {

    $nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface | Where-Object {($_.VirtualMachine.id).ToLower() -eq ($id).ToLower()}
    $nic.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools = $backendPool

    Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $nic -AsJob    
}    

If ($ErrorMessages) {
    Write-Error "Deployment returned the following errors: $ErrorMessages";
    Return
}
```

You can find on my github as well: https://github.com/azurekid/blog/blob/master/Update-BackendPool.ps1

Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: It's ok to include links to other sites in an answer, but the most relevant parts of the linked code should also be included in the question itself, since links might break in the future.